# Automatically scroll to the right

Tags: css, scroll

I want to automatically scroll the page to the right. Is it possible with CSS, or I have to use Javascript - JQuery for that?

Then, I would hide the left of the page with:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need [`Jquery`](http://jquery.com/) to acomplish that with a function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var s =$('div').width();    
    $('body').scrollLeft(s).css('overflow','hidden')
})
```

Check this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bp4zF/

Comment: Seems that works only with float elements. When I scroll $(document) to the left (`$('body')` doesn't work), it scrolls, but when I after hide the overflow (`$('body').css('overflow','hidden')`) it scrolls again to the left before hiding it.

Comment: It would be something like this (with a margin to the left) http://jsfiddle.net/Bp4zF/2/

Comment: @ManoloSalsas don't get your point what is wrong in your fiddle?

Comment: It doesn't scroll to the right... If you delete the overflow part, you'll see that you still can scroll

Comment: @ManoloSalsas ah! right that's because I only scroll based on the width of the div but you can add the margin-left and any values you want to make it full right ..... [Like This](http://jsfiddle.net/Bp4zF/4/) or make an external container [Like This Another](http://jsfiddle.net/Bp4zF/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Acheive with javascript.

```
window.scrollTo(x, y);
```

and

```
window.scrollBy(dx,dy) (ref)
```